# async function not working, cannot update and upload image

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, amazon-s3, async-await

Im working on a function where there is page asking user for a profile picture and some info.
so far thats what i have

```
router.post('/edit/:id', async function(req, res) {
  let user
  const id = req.params.id
  try{
    user = await User.findById(id)
    user.firstname= req.user.firstname,
    user.lastname= req.user.lastname,
    user.religion= req.user.religion,
    user.education= req.user.education,
    user.language= req.user.language,
    user.lookingfor=req.body.lookingfor,
    user.preferEdu=req.user.preferEdu,
    user.preferReligion= req.user.preferReligion,
    user.bio= req.user.bio
    if (req.file != null && req.file !== '') {
      await upload(req, res, (err) => {
        if(err){
          console.log(err)
         } else {
           if(req.file == undefined){
             console.log('no file')
           } else {
             console.log(req.file)
            User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: id}, {$set: {
               imageurl: req.file.location
             }}, {new: true}, (err, result) => {
               res.redirect('/dashboard')
             })
           }
         }
      })
    }

  } catch{
    if (user != null) {
      console.log ('no user')
    } else {
      res.redirect('/dashboard')
    }

  }

})
```

the page just jump back to '/dashboard' without anything being saved

before i have a function that just handle upload images, and it was sucessful

```
router.post('/edit/:id', function(req, res) {
  const id = req.params.id
    upload(req, res, (err) => {
    if(err){
     console.log(err)
    } else {
      if(req.file == undefined){
        console.log('no file')
      } else {
        console.log(req.file)
       User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: id}, {$set: {
          imageurl: req.file.location
        }}, {new: true}, (err, result) => {
          res.redirect('/dashboard')
        })


      }
    }
  });
});
```

I can see the image was uploaded to amazon s3 and req.file.location was logged in the console. but it was not saved in my mongo database.
any help will be appreciated! thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to use capital letter of 'l' of location. You should switch the line req.file.location to req.file.Location. S3 return json with keys having a captial letter as initials.

Hope, this helps! let me know if that works!

Comment: hi! thanks for the reply, i think it should be "l" because when i changed to capital it gave me undefined when i console.log (req.file.Locationi)

Comment: req.file.Location.

Comment: and can you share your upload function?

Comment: var upload = multer({
  fileFilter,
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'user-image2',
    acl: 'public-read',
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now().toString())
    }
  })
}).single('image')